# Custom legend in fille.contour3

Tags: r, data-visualization, legend, contour

I am trying to use a costume legend with filled.contour3, like in this example:

```
colorRampPalette(c('white','blue','green','yellow','red','darkmagenta','darkviolet'))(15)
```

When I use filled.contour3 with the predefined legend (e.g., terrain.colors) it works fine.
But if I try to add a costume legend (e.g., terrain.colors(10)) I get an error message:

```
Error in .filled.contour(as.double(x), as.double(y), z, as.double(levels),  : 
could not find function "color.palette"
```

Here is a sample code:

```
#Generate some fake data
x = rep(c(10,11,12),length = 9)
y = rep(c(1,2,3),each = 3)
z = runif(n=9,min = 0,max = 1)
xcoords = unique(x)
ycoords = unique(y)
surface.matrix = matrix(z,nrow=length(xcoords),ncol=length(ycoords),byrow=T)

#this works:
filled.contour3(xcoords,ycoords,surface.matrix,color=terrain.colors,xlab = "",ylab = "",xlim = c(min(xcoords),max(xcoords)),ylim = c(min(ycoords),max(ycoords)),zlim = c(min(surface.matrix),max(surface.matrix)))

#this doesn't work:
filled.contour3(xcoords,ycoords,surface.matrix,color=terrain.colors(10),xlab = "",ylab = "",xlim = c(min(xcoords),max(xcoords)),ylim = c(min(ycoords),max(ycoords)),zlim = c(min(surface.matrix),max(surface.matrix)))
```

I use R 3.0.3 on Win7 64
Thanks
,Ilik

Comment: Perhaps you could specify with which package this is being done.

Comment: filled.contour3 is not part of a package. it is a function found here: [link](https://r-forge.r-project.org/scm/viewvc.php/pkg/R/filled.contour3.R?view=markup&root=detsel)

Comment: Feel free to add this to your question to make it  complete.

Answer (score 1):

`?filled.contour` has two options to set color:

**color.palette**: a color palette *function* to be used to assign colors in the plot.

**col**: an explicit *set* of colors to be used in the plot. This argument overrides any palette function specification. There should be one less color than levels

You're supplying a vector of colors to `color`, which is interpreted as `color.palette`. If you want to supply a predefined vector of colors, use `col` instead:

```
cols = colorRampPalette(c('white','blue','green','yellow','red','darkmagenta','darkviolet'))(15)
filled.contour(xcoords,ycoords,surface.matrix,col=cols,xlab = "",ylab = "",xlim = c(min(xcoords),max(xcoords)),ylim = c(min(ycoords),max(ycoords)),zlim = c(min(surface.matrix),max(surface.matrix)))
```

Comment: Thanks. I didn't see any documentation about this.